# cannot enable redis-zstd in php:8.0.2-fpm-buster

Tags: package, command, pecl, zstd

In a container based on "php:8.0.2-fpm-buster" image, I run

```
pecl install zstd
echo "extension=zstd.so" > /path/to/php.ini
```

then run

```
pecl install redis
enable zstd compression support? [no] : yes
```

The output is

```
checking for libzstd files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libzstd distribution
```

Is there a solution or a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by running

```
apt-get -y install libzstd-dev
```

Check [this github issue](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/2118) for detail.